# insert data into two tables with a single form. Laravel : error Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, laravel, forms, post

So I would like to know how to insert data into two different table but linke, Table Poste(offer, ad) and company, each ad is link to a company, I created two Model and only 1 Controller, Post and Company and Postecontroller.

```
Schema::create('entreprises', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nomEntreprise');
            $table->string('adresseEntreprise');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('postes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('idPoste');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idEntreprise');
            $table->string('nomPoste');
            $table->text('descriptionPoste');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('idEntreprise')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('entreprises')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
public function create()
    {
        $postes = Poste::all();
        $entreprises = Entreprise::all();
        return view('postes.create', compact('postes','entreprises'));
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'nomPoste'=>'required|min:3',
            'descriptionPoste'=>'required|min:3'
        ]);
        $data2 = $request->validate([
            'nomEntreprise'=>'required|min:3',
            'adresseEntreprise'=>'required|min:3'
        ]);
        Poste::create($data);
        Entreprise::create($data2);



        return back();
    }
class Poste extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = ['nomPoste','descriptionPoste','idEntreprise'];

    public function entreprise()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Entreprise::class,'idEntreprise');
    }
}
protected $fillable = ['nomEntreprise', 'adresseEntreprise'];

    public function poste()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Poste::class);
    }
```

when I insert data through the factory it works well because I manage to display a Post with his company by id. but by from the insertion caused me  an error like:Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (projetetudiant.postes, CONSTRAINT 
 postes_identreprise_foreign FOREIGN KEY (idEntreprise) REFERENCES entreprises (id) ON DELETE CASCADE).

i'm new and juste strated to lurn laravel, and i'm already stuck so pls realy need help ! sorry for my english i'm a french dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not insert a post record if you don't have a enterprise record.
In your case you are inserting post before enterprise, that's the error.

Your store function will become:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'nomPoste'=>'required|min:3',
        'descriptionPoste'=>'required|min:3'
    ]);
    $data2 = $request->validate([
        'nomEntreprise'=>'required|min:3',
        'adresseEntreprise'=>'required|min:3'
    ]);

    $newEnterprise = Entreprise::create($data2);
    Poste::create($data + [
        'idEntreprise' => $newEnterprise->id
    ]);

    return back();
}
```